# Simplest way to send email based on new row in POSTGRES database

Tags: postgresql, email

I have a database based on user data, and I'd like to have an email automatically send every time a new row with a specific value is added to the database.
For example, let's say I have a table with a user's email, phone number, and state, and I want to have an email send every time a row in the database where the state='Arizona' is created, how can I do this?

Comment: Write an application in your favorite programming language. Not clear why you want this because if your database is used for a successful application, your mailbox gets flooded. Create a html dashboard and show whatever metric you need. Email is not a reliable and/or scalable tool for metrics.

Comment: In a trigger use https://www.brandolabs.com/pgmail/